# Prefix and Path for Cross GCC in Eclipse

Tags: compiling, eclipse, gcc, c++

I'm pretty new in ubuntu and have a problem with it.

I wanna to write a c++ program in eclipse and compile it with cross gcc.

At the first i Added "CDT" from "help-->install new software"

Now when I want to create a new c++ project a pop up ask me for
**Cross Compiler prefix and Cross Compiler Path**

I have no idea what shoud I do ?and what they means?
thanks for any help

Comment: What target platform do you want to cross compile for?

Comment: Unfotunately I m not sure...
I choose cross gcc rather than linux gcc becuase i thought at the end i can run program in both windows and linux
I think the target platform is windows

Comment: @MahmoodAghvami Unfotunately nobody could answer your question if you don't know what you are trying to do. If you're going to cross compile anything then you'll need to know platform you'll be targetting. By default `cross gcc` will be using your host gcc and thus it probably will be same as `linux gcc`. You could find installed toolchains under `/usr/lib/gcc`.